# Submit a form when enter is pressed in a textarea in React?

Tags: reactjs

How can I make a form submit when a user pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd> in a `<textarea>`? The default behaviour is to insert a linebreak into the `<textarea>`.

```
<form className="" onSubmit={newComment}>
    <textarea type="text" rows="3" name="body" />
    <button className="btn" type="submit">
        Comment
    </button>
</form>
```

Should I have an `onChange` event on the `<textarea>`, and in a function test to see if the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key was pressed? This is how I would do it with vanilla JavaScript but I couldn't find the key event in React's synthetic event.

Comment: use `onKeyDown` handler and check for `event.keyCode`, it will work. [Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mayankshukla5031/xjzecqfr/)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Your textarea is an uncontrolled element. This is an acceptable approach, however, facebook encourages the use of controlled inputs.

Anyway, here is how to do it for uncontrolled forms:

```
onEnterPress = (e) => {
  if(e.keyCode == 13 && e.shiftKey == false) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.myFormRef.submit();
  }
}

render() {
  return (
    <form ref={el => this.myFormRef = el} className="">
      <textarea type="text" rows="3" name="body" onKeyDown={this.onEnterPress} />
      <button className="btn" type="submit">
        Comment
      </button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

You can also use `id` instead of `refs` above.

Comment: we can directly call the submit function also `newComment()`, instead of ref :)

Comment: @MayankShukla, true. I can't see that function anywhere in op code, so I excluded that bit.

Comment: @Chris, as you mentionned yourself, *uncontrolled* is one of two ways of handling texteareas in React. The question was "How can I make a form submit when a user pressed 'enter' in **a** textarea?", and you answer *here is how to do it for uncontrolled forms*. So I'd say answer is incomplete, isn't it ? :D

Comment: @CyrilCHAPON sorry for late answer. The solution wouldn't vary for controlled forms either.

Comment: e.shiftKey is not working. It always return false

Comment: @huykon225 perhaps your event is triggered before or after the shift was pressed

Comment: oh that's right. I will check carefully again

Answer (score 6):

With react 17 this does not seem to work anymore. Instead use `requestSubmit()`.

> The HTMLFormElement.submit() method submits a given form.
>
> This method is similar, but not identical to, activating a form's
> submit button. When invoking this method directly, however:
>
> ```
> No submit event is raised. In particular, the form's onsubmit event handler is not run.
> Constraint validation is not triggered.
> ```
>
> The HTMLFormElement.requestSubmit() method is identical to activating
> a form's submit button and does not have these differences.

Further reading here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit

```js
    onEnterPress = (e) => {
      if(e.keyCode == 13 && e.shiftKey == false) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.myFormRef.requestSubmit();
      }
    }
    
    render() {
      return (
        <form ref={el => this.myFormRef = el} className="">
          <textarea type="text" rows="3" name="body" onKeyDown={this.onEnterPress} />
          <button className="btn" type="submit">
            Comment
          </button>
        </form>
      );
    }
```

Comment: Very much correct sir, accepted answer should be updated. Thanks.

Comment: This works in 2024

Answer (score 0):

For functional component
edit form element as requirements

```
  const functionalComponent = () => {
  const addData = () => {
    localStorage.setItem("anyitem","anyData")
  }

  EnterPress = (e) => {
    if (e.keyCode == 13 && e.shiftKey == false) {
      e.preventDefault();
      addData();
    }}
    return (
      <>
      <textarea type="text" rows="3" name="body" onKeyDown={EnterPress} />
      </>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Please add some more details do not post code only answers

Answer (score 0):

This snippet based on previous responses could be useful:

```
export const SubmitOnEnterTextArea = (
  props: React.TextareaHTMLAttributes<HTMLTextAreaElement>,
) => (
  <textarea
    {...props}
    onKeyDown={(e) => {
      if (e.key === "Enter" && !e.shiftKey && "form" in e.target) {
        e.preventDefault();
        (e.target.form as HTMLFormElement).requestSubmit();
      }
    }}
  ></textarea>
);
```